# Can anyone help me solve this limit (step by step)?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{x^3-13x^2+51x-63}{x^3-4x^2-3x+18}$$

source : https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1hpv.png

I tried direct substitution but I ended up with the indeterminate form 0/0 so I need to factorize the limit or simplize it in order to evaluate it but I couldn't find a way to do it, thought you can help me out :) .Thanks in advance

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $x-3$ or use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: you can make a change of variable $x = 3 + h$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4Use L'Hopitals rule to simplifly the matters. Let $f(x) = x^3 - 13x^2 + 51 x - 63 $ and $g(x) = x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x + 18$. Since $f/g \to 0/0$ as $x \to 3$, then

$$ \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{f}{g} = \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{ f'}{g'} = \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{3x^2 - 26x + 51}{3x^2 - 8x - 3}$$

which again is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, so we apply $L'hopitals$ rule again:

$$ \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{3x^2 - 26x + 51}{3x^2 - 8x - 3} = \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{6x - 26}{6x - 8} = \frac{ 6(3) - 26}{6(3) - 8} = \frac{-8}{10} = - \frac{4}{5}$$

Comment: You mean -4/5 but ty anyway that helped me alot :D

Comment: Should a wrong answer be tagged as the best ??

Comment: wats wrong about it brotha

Comment: Haha, you fixed it after the fact. I'll keep my downvote.

Comment: well he only divided wrong but the method is all i wanted so yes that is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that $3$ is a zero of the numerator and denominator, that means that $x-3$ is a factor of both. So, divide $x-3$ out of both and you be left with two quadratics. Factor those and simplify.  You should be able to plug $3$ in at that point.

Answer (score 1):

this is a little bit of cheating. but if you realized that $(x-3)^2$ is factor in both numerator and denominator, then $$ \frac{x^3-13x^2+51x-63}{x^3-4x^2-3x+18}= \frac{(x-3)^2(x-7)}{(x-3)^2(x+2)} =\frac{x-7}{x+2} \to -\frac{4}{5} \text{ as } x \to 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think You can factor out $(x-3)$ from both parts of the fraction to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $x=3+y$ gives you
$$\frac{x^3-13x^2+51x-63}{x^3-4x^2-3x+18}=\frac{y^3-4y^2}{y^3+5y^2}=\frac{y^2}{y^2}\frac{y-4}{y+5}.$$

You can conclude.

Comment: Why this downvote ?